# Removing the same method from Event

Tags: c#, events, methods

If I have reference to event ThrowEvent, method X() and subscribe like that :

```
ThrowEvent += X;
ThrowEvent += X;
ThrowEvent += X;
```

What happend when I try to make

```
ThrowEvent -= X;
```

Will it remove the first or the last added method ?

Comment: Try it, I'm fairly sure it removes the last event added..

Comment: Does it matter? Result is the same - X method will be called 2 times instead of 3 times.

Comment: 1+1+1=3; 3-1=2; Which one of them was subtracted? :)

Comment: If we have another method called Y, then subscribve them like += X, +=Y, +=X, then removing -= X so which X would be removed? The first or the last one ?

Comment: Again, it doesn't matter. Important, thta when you write -=X, it removes X and not Y.

Comment: In some cases it could be important, e.g. ThrowEvent += X; ThrowEvent += Y; ThrowEvent += X; ThrowEvent -= X; what will be the sequence? X than Y (if the last delegate is removed) or Y than X (if the first delegate is removed)?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: delegate invocation order is not specified by standard. The test like in your answer shows, that there is some well defined order, but this is implementation specific. Maybe OP means that different X delegates belong to different instances (lik1 a1.Method1 and a2.Method1). In this case they are not equal. But I don't know exactly what does he mean...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily test it yourself:

```
private static void A(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Console.Out.Write('A');
}

private static void B(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Console.Out.Write('B');
}

...

EventHandler eh = null;

eh += A;
eh += A;
eh += B;
eh += A;
eh -= A;

eh(null, EventArgs.Empty);
```

The output is "**AAB**", so we can conclude, that *the last delegete* is removed

Answer (score 0):

In the context of event subscription, two delegates are the same if:

```
1. They point to the same static method,
or:
2. They point to the same instance method of the same class instance.
```

So, in your question, X must meet this condition. It doesn't matter which one of these `X` are removed. The point is, after `X` was subscribed 3 times, this method is called 3 times, when event is raised. After `X` is unsubscribed once, it is called 2 times, when event is raised.